# Pick some properties from generated Instance of type is not working, why?

Tags: typescript, mobx, typescript2.0, mobx-state-tree

Trying to generate an new type with only some properties, but I'm getting nothing..

```js
const User = types.model({
    id: types.identifier,
    username: types.maybe(types.string),
    email: types.maybe(types.string),
});
type TUser = Instance<typeof User>;
type TDatabaseUser = Pick<TUser, 'id' | 'email'>
```

> TDatabaseUser has no properties.. and should have `id` and `email`

What I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working as intended.

```js
import { Instance, types } from "mobx-state-tree";

const User = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  username: types.maybe(types.string),
  email: types.maybe(types.string)
});
type TUser = Instance<typeof User>;
type TDatabaseUser = Pick<TUser, "id" | "email">;

const dbUser: TDatabaseUser = {
  id: "1",
  email: "test@test.com",
  // id and email works, but username gives rise to an error.
  username: "does not work"
};
```

Comment: You are right.. For some reason.. WebStorm is not showing this error

Comment: @ridermansb Great! Ah, I see, that's a bummer.